# insert range between ranges

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to insert WORD range object between 2 objects for example:

```
Sub test()
  Dim pRange1 As Word.Range
  Dim pRange2 As Word.Range
  ' ActiveDocument.Range => String "12"
  Set pRange1 = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(1) 'pRange1 =1
  '
  Set pRange2 = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(2) 'pRange1 =2
  pRange1.InsertAfter (3) 'pRange1 =13
  
  
End Sub
```

My target is to insert a new range object between pRange1 and Prange2 but the result of using the insertAfter method is that pRange1 now have 2 characters
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace what is between the end of the first range and the start of the second range.  Insert after does exactly that.  It inserts, it does not replace.

```
Sub test()
  Dim pRange1 As Word.Range
  Dim pRange2 As Word.Range
  Dim myReplaceBetween As Word.Range

  ' ActiveDocument.Range => String "12"
  Set pRange1 = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(5) 'pRange1 =1
  '
  Set pRange2 = ActiveDocument.Range.Characters(9) 'pRange1 =2
  
  Set myReplaceBetween = pRange1.Duplicate
  
  myReplaceBetween.Start = pRange1.End + 1
  myReplaceBetween.End = pRange2.Start - 1


  myReplaceBetween.Text = "This is the new text"

End Sub
```

I'll leave you to work out what should happen if myBetweenRange has a negative span(start>end)

Answer updated 21 Dec 2020 due revision of the myReplaceRange

Comment: The execution fails in the line "set myReplaceBetween = New Word.Range" with the error "Invalid use of New keyword", how can I correct this?

Comment: delete the new?

Comment: After deleting the "new" got the error ""Compile Error: Method or data member not found"

Comment: I updated the answer with code I tested on my PC.